# using multiple font family in same sentence

Tags: xetex, pdftex

change the font family and size of The quick Brown
change the font family of fox
do not change the font of jumps over the lazy dog
I am using windows

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Ofont{Oswald Regular}
\newfontfamily\Rfont{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\RLfont{Roboto Light}
\newfontfamily\Afont{Algerian}
\begin{document}
{\Ofont{\fontsize{25}{50}\selectfont The quick brown} {\Rfont fox} jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... surely you have a mismatched brace (the first opening brace is never closed).

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Put in several `\fontname\font`commands  to display the font name being used. "jumps over the lazy dog" is using the \Ofont font switch.